# How do i set up tor command line

Tags: windows, tor-install

I'm using the tor expert bundle for a project and need to configure tor to make a password for control port access to use for an auto switcher. Tried to do `tor --hash-password` Password but seems like tor is not in the system yet.

Comment: What do you mean "Tor is not in the system yet"? If you've just unzipped the directory you downloaded, then Tor will be in there, it won't have been "installed" in the normal way. (So just typing `tor` at the command prompt won't work because it's not been placed into a directory that's in your path.)

Comment: i tried adding ;"path to tor" in the environmental variables path but that didnt work. All i need is to access the tor command line so i can set up that password

Comment: If you know where Tor is, then just run it from there instead of adding it to your path. For example, on the command line, and assuming a Linux machine (change as appropriate for Windows): `/<path>/<to>/<tor>/tor --hash-password <password>`

Comment: I attempted to run tor that way but this is what i shows when i add "| more". 
C:\Users\The Black Box\Downloads\tor-win32-0.2.7.6\Tor>tor --hash-password password | more
Jan 05 10:01:44.129 [warn] Path for GeoIPFile (<default>) is relative and will r
esolve to C:\Users\The Black Box\Downloads\tor-win32-0.2.7.6\Tor\<default>. Is t
his what you wanted?
Jan 05 10:01:44.129 [warn] Path for GeoIPv6File (<default>) is relative and will
 resolve to C:\Users\The Black Box\Downloads\tor-win32-0.2.7.6\Tor\<default>. Is
 this what you wanted?
16:DBB32F0387AED56E602FD2D97E3E9017C082D513CB889E2A76C2DF55C2

Comment: Okay - that's the output you want. The string at the end is the hash of your password. To know what to do with it, have a look at [this](https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/the_little_relay_that_could.html) quick tutorial. (i.e. Basically add it to your torrc file.)

Answer (score 1):

If you used a TBB, especially on Windows - of course it's not in your PATH, so just typing `tor xxxx` will trigger an error. In your TBB install folder find `tor.exe`(Windows) or `tor`(non-windows) binary, change directory into this folder and make a command call there. In non-windows use `./tor` instead of `tor` if it still fails. NEVER add tor binary to your PATH variable regardless of the OS you're using : it's insecure.

Comment: Why adding tor binary to PATH variable is insecure?

Comment: it can be easily detected by commands like `which tor` with even an unprivileged users, it can be possibe abused by malware attempting to attack the host by starting with alternative options and command protocol and later be configured through it. And many more

Comment: Alexey, can you explain your thoughts on having tor available to unpriviledged users?  I installed tor on a Linux machine on which I don't have superuser status using Homebrew.  It works fine.  Why should this be a problem?